# Python 3. Подписать электронной подписью на сайте

Tags: python, python-3.x, цифровая-подпись

Всем привет!

На сайте есть следующая форма:
[image: Форма на сайте]

Если в поле "XML запроса" загружена xml, то при нажатии на кнопку "Подписать" страница обращается к CAdES Browser Plug-in, запускается целый букет js скриптов cpro, происходит подписание xml и отправка POST запроса.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Python 3 реализовать подписание xml из формы?
Само подписание в данном случае ведь происходит на стороне клиента?

Как я понимаю на сервере, на котором выполняется скрипт Python должен быть установлен Крипто про. Возможно необходимо использовать библиотеку Pycades?

Возможно проще всего спарсить значение xml из формы в переменную и подписать уже это значение, а потом просто подставить в POST запрос?

Какую библиотеку лучше использовать для подписания подписью, созданную с помощью криптопровайдера Крипто про? Подойдет ли для этого signxml?

Может хотя бы теоретически объясните как такое реализовать, или может примеры подобного у кого есть?

Comment: По работе, когда делал интерфейс ГИС ГМП работал с КриптоПро на java. Там, XML нужно было трансформировать, приводя к определенному формату, типа убрать пробелы между тегами, префиксы пространства имен в алфавитном порядке и т.п. Далее, подавалась эта XML в метод, который имея сертификат высчитывал подпись (по сути, хеш от строки XML) и это значение записывалось в запрос (тоже XML) в определенное поле. Это теория, которую помню :D

Answer (score 0):

`signxml` - то что вам нужно. Вот пример с https://pypi.org/project/signxml/ :

```
from lxml import etree
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier

data_to_sign = "<Test/>"
cert = open("example.pem").read()
key = open("example.key").read()
root = etree.fromstring(data_to_sign)
signed_root = XMLSigner().sign(root, key=key, cert=cert)
```

Он добавляет в оригинальный xml `<Text/>` подпись и в результате получается такой xml (привожу сокращенно):

```
<Test>
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <ds:Reference URI="">
            <ds:Transforms>
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
               <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11" />
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>KP3ncf09YSgkeTt+i4PR+W0AMvUTo7M8gu0z15piPMc=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue>тут-значение подписи</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
         <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>многабукаф</ds:X509Certificate>
         </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
   </ds:Signature>
</Test>
```

Для работы с `signxml` вам нужно только извлечь (конвертировать) сертификат и ключ в один из форматов, который понимает `signxml`, если они в другом формате у вас сейчас. Я не знаком с Крипто про, но бывают [разные форматы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743415/what-are-the-differences-between-pem-cer-and-der/22743616) хранения сертификатов и ключей.

Comment: Проверил, signxml к сожалению не подойдет. После подписания на сервер отправляется POST запрос, который содержит исходную xml и в отдельном параметре "signature" передает подпись (много строк в формате Base64). Если раскодировать Base64, то там содержится в том числе вся информация об открытом сертификате. Т.о. подпись осуществляется с помощью Крипто Про. И надо такую же подпись получить с помощью Pyton